# 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' in discord.js v13 audio/music bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, voice

I have this simple Music Bot for me and my friends, but after upgrading to v13 of discord.js some things just don´t work anymore... I already changed some things up just like the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#threads) tels you to do. Someone got an idea what is wrong here??

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const Music = require('discordjs/voice');

console.log("is this working");

//  PLAYER
 client.on("messageCreate", async message => {

  if(message.content == 'goplay') {
  const url = args[0];
  if(!url) return message.channel.send('no url');


  const stream = ytdl(url, { filter: 'audioonly'});

  const channel = message.member.voice.channel;

  const player = Music.createAudioPlayer();
  const ressource = Music.createAudioResource(stream);

  const connection = Music.joinVoiceChannel({
   channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
   guildId: message.channel.guild,
   adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
  });

  player.play(ressource)
  connection.subscribe(player);

  }
});
```

[here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPl1S.png)

Comment: Do you create an index-voice.js (or used to have one) on your bot's folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a `package.json` error. Make sure you have a package.json created.

Use the command `npm init`, and fill out the needed information, to have it automatically create everything use `npm init -y` (and then make sure to install all of your npm packages)

Comment: So that did something. I´m sorry for that amateur mistake... Thanks man